# Skip TreeView's AfterSelect when changing window's state

Tags: vb.net

The below line triggers `TreeView`'s `AfterSelect` in my application:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Is there any way to disable that? It is not quite clear to me why changing window's state would fire that event in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this happening in VS2013, although the event is fired during form load. One way to handle this is to use a boolean flag (`loading`, for example) that is global to the form and initialized to True. At the beginning of the AfterSelect handler, check the flag and exit if true. You can also set the flag (temporarily) whenever the windowstate is changed.

Comment: That's interesting, debugger suggested as if the event was fired by `WindowState`. Anyway, adding the flag solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: By the way, is there any reasoning behind the event being triggered during form load?

Comment: None that I know of, although Microsoft says it's "by design".